# Color rendering inconsistency

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

Has anyone had experience with inconsistent colors from svg? I've got a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmoore38/xurDA/12/), and each time the fiddle is run the colors are different, sometimes greener and sometimes bluer. Is this anything that can be controlled? Thank you!

Comment: Well if you wouldn't use random data, the opacity would be consistent. What's the problem? Didn't you write the code on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `fill-opacity` based on the dataset length `1/dataset.length`, but the dataset is a random length. Your fill opacity will change, which is giving the appearance of different colors.